# Obtener el ID de un elemento al hacer hover sobre el mismo

Tags: jquery

Buen dia a todos, tengo varios elementos que creo dinamicamente, entonces les agrego la funcion hover con jquery de la siguiente manera:

```js
 $(document).on('mouseenter', '.abtnTest', function ()
{
  console.log("In Hover: " + this.Id);
}).on('mouseleave', '.abtnTest', function ()
{
  console.log("Out Hover: " + this.Id);
});
```

Intento como esta el codigo dentro de console.log, de obtener el Id del elemento al cual le hago hover, pero no me funciona. Saben si hay alguna posibilidad de obtener el Id sobre el cual se le hace hover?.

Nota: los elementos se crean dinamicamente.

Comment: qué elementos quieres aumentar o modificar? son imágenes, inputs...?

Comment: es un span, deseo obtener su id, y le agrego la funcion hover con la clase ".abtnTest"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener el id del elemento al que realizas `hover` el código es el siguiente:

```
$(".abtnTest").hover(function() {
    let elementId = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(elementId);
});
```

O también:

```
$(".abtnTest").on("hover", function() {
    let elementId = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(elementId);
});
```

El segundo se utiliza más cuando vas agregando elementos dinámicamente.

Answer (score 0):

podemos hacer uso de las funciones **onmouseover** y **onmouseout** de html para llamar a las funciones que te permitan obtener el id. Supongo que lo siguiente es lo que necesitas implementar:

```html
    <script>
        function adentro(x) {
            console.log("ahora estoy adentro");
        }
    
        function afuera(x) {
            console.log("ahora estoy afuera")
        }
    </script>
    
    
    <span onmouseover="adentro(this)" onmouseout="afuera(this)">
        <h2>Pollo</h2>
    </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando `this.id` puedes lograrlo. El ámbito de las funciones anónimas (no funciones con flecha [`e => process(e)`]) para eventos de elementos es el mismo elemento

```js
$(document.body).append($('<button id="btn">Prueba</button>').hover(function(e){ console.log(this.id, "over")}, function(e){ console.log(this.id, "out")}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```